# max and min of array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

So, I am entering double values into array, then founding sum(without max and min), average, max and min. Everything is ok, but min is permanently 0, and I don't know what to do;

NOTE: no use of `Max()`and `Min()` methods

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double avr = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double max;
    double min;
    Console.WriteLine("how many numbers?");
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    double[] arr = new double[b];
    max = arr[0];
    min = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (arr[i] >= max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }

        else if (arr[i] <= min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    sum = sum - max - min;
    avr = sum / (b - 2);

    Console.WriteLine("sum = {0},average = {1}, max = {2}, min = {3}", sum, avr, max, min);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: initialize all of your doubles = to `0d or 0.0`

Comment: max = double.minvalue; min = double.maxvalue; then convert the else if into a simple if

Comment: yes make the `else if (arr[i] <= min)` simply `if (arr[i] <= min)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use default values of `double` to initialize `min` and `max` - so both will be set to 0 prior any iteration. So `min` will work incorrectly if all elements greater than zero, `max` - when all elements less than zero.

Fix

- use `double.MinValue` / `double.MaxValue` to corresponding min/max so any actual value will satisfy `if` condition
   `max = double.MinValue;`
- better yet split reading of array and computing statistics - than using `arr[0]` will actually contain valid user provided value instead of default.

Comment: can you write your 2nd fix(about splitting) more detailed please?

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize max and min you set it to `arr[0]` which would be 0. That means your min is all ready at a very low value.

Do `double.MinVale` and `double.MaxValue` to initialize your max and min variables instead.

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you try to achieve. I removed the array, because it has no function. There were two problems (also see comments in code):
1) The `else if` statement: a value can both be the minimum and maximum at the same time and the else will never be reached when the entered numbers are always higher then the previous ones.
2) The initial minimum value should be the maximum possible value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double avr = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double max = 0;
    double min = Double.MaxValue; // *** Initially set to maximum possible number ***
    Console.WriteLine("How many numbers?");
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        double number = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (number >= max)
        {
            max = number;
        }
        if (number <= min) // *** The else is removed here ***
        {
            min = number;
        }
        sum += number;
    }

    sum = sum - max - min; // Exclude lowest and hightest value
    avr = sum / (b - 2); // Average excluding lowest and highest value

    Console.WriteLine("sum = {0}, average = {1}, max = {2}, min = {3}", sum, avr, max, min);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```